# Fundamental group of surface of genus $2$ using van Kampen

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I got confused when calculating the fundamental group of $\Sigma_2$.

We can think of $\Sigma_g$ as the union of two toruses $T_1, T_2$ which intersect in a circle $S^1$.

Using the fundamental polygon, one gets that $\pi_1(T_1)=<a_1,b_1|[a_1,b_1]>$ and $\pi_1(T_2)=<a_2,b_2|[a_2,b_2]>.$ Further the normal subgroup $N$ is generated by $[a_1,b_1]\,[a_2,b_2]=1.$

Thus van Kampen implies that $$\pi_1(\Sigma_2)=\frac{\pi_1(T_1) * \pi_1(T_2)}N=<a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2|\,[a_1,b_1],[a_2,b_2],[a_1b_1]\,[a_2,b_2]>.$$

But the literature says that $\pi_1(\Sigma_2)=<a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2|\,[a_1b_1]\,[a_2,b_2]>.$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since $a_1$ commutes with $b_1$ and $a_2$ commutes with $b_2$ then obviously always $[a_1, b_1][a_2, b_2]=1$. I.e. these two groups are isomorphic since the last relation is a consequence of previous 2.

Comment: @freakish this is clear, but how can we show that $[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]=1$ implies that $a_1$ commutes with $b_1$

Comment: No, the implication is other way around. $[a_1, b_1]=1$ and $[a_2, b_2]=1$ so $[a_1, b_1][a_2,b_2]=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know much about algebra, so i need to ask these dumb questions...  
@freakish: If we only have the implication in one direction, then why can we conclude more than that one group is a subgroup of the other?

Comment: Oh, wait, there's no `,` in the other group. My mistake. But the group should be $\pi_1(\sum_2)=<a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2\ |\ [a_1, b_1], [a_2, b_2]>$, shouldn't it? Isn't that the one the literature says? That's unlikely that the one you've written is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The used partition of the Torus is wrong.

> We can think of $\Sigma_g$ as the union of two toruses $T_1, T_2$ which intersect in a circle $S^1$.

This would give a double Torus united with the two disks which $S^1$ bounds. The proper way to do it is to remove these disks first, and then glue the tori together.

The fundametal group $\pi_1(T_1\setminus D^2)=<a_1,b_1>$, because $T\setminus D^2$ deformation retracts to the wedge sum of the two boundary circles $a_1$ and $b_1$.

Then 
$$\pi_1(\Sigma_2)=\frac{\pi_1(T_1\setminus D^2) * \pi_1(T_2\setminus D^2)}N=<a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2|\,[a_1b_1]\,[a_2,b_2]>.$$